# How to add custom HTTP Headers in Asp.Net-MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a custom handler that looks like follow:

```
public class SitHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process request");
        // Call the inner handler.
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        return response;
    }
}
```

and registered in the class `WebApiConfig`:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      // Web API configuration and services

      //Delegating Handlers
      config.MessageHandlers.Add(new SitHandler());

      // Web API routes
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

      /*config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "DefaultApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );*/
    }
}
```

and have following route:

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class SignInController : Controller
{
    [Route("", Name = "Default")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View();
    }
}
```

Now when I start the server it show me the correct page as expected:
[image]

But the request does not goi throught the handler, why?
And what is an innerhandler?

```
// Call the inner handler.
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: You are mixing up MVC and Web API. You are adding your delegate handler to the WebApi pipeline while your controller is from MVC as it inherits from `Controller` and not `ApiController`. What version of api.net-mvc are your using?

Comment: aha. How can I add a handler to MVC?

Comment: You should clarify what your intentions are first. That way others can provide you with answers relevant with what you are trying to do.

Comment: My intention is, to add custom http header.

Comment: ...to Web API or MVC?

Comment: I want to impliment in MVC.

Comment: Then you need to reword your question. "How to add custom HTTP Headers in Asp.Net-MVC" or something to that effect. I would advise that you search for questions that already address this otherwise your question will be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I did it. I thought delegatehandler is also in mvc.

Comment: You should look into global filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For MVC you will need to add an `ActionFilterAttribute`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class MyCustomFilter : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Process response");
        //From here you have access to the response to process what you need
        //eg: context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("MyCustomHeaderName","value");

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

you can then either use you attribute on an action...

```
[MyCustomFilter]
[Route("", Name = "Default")]
public ActionResult Index(){...}
```

, class...

```
[MyCustomFilter]
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class SignInController : Controller {...}
```

, or set it globally...

```
public class FilterConfig {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new MyCustomFilter());
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks so much for reponse, but it does not work. I used the attribute as class and it does not go through filter. Then I try to register in the `FilterConfig` class, it throws an exception `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Web.Mvc.dll`. I've forgot to mention, that I am using Web MVC and Web API in the project.

Comment: Do you mean `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`? I tried it and it works but I could not find `Response.Headers.Add`.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant. I mixed up filter for web api and mvc. that was a mistake on my part. I've updated the answer with the correct types.