# Programmatically accessing custom response headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to programmatically get/change the custom response headers specified in the web.config (system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders), but I seem unable to get them. I don't want to simply get the header specified in the web.config (by opening it), but rather getting access to my custom headers via HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers or similar and have the opportunity to change them for each request.

I've tried in many different ways, like using a Owin middleware, or via Application_PreSendRequestHeaders in Global.asax.

Any idea how I could get them or the reason for this behavior? The only thing I can imagine is that these headers are added after the whole ASP.NET execution, and therefore I don't have the chance to interact with them.

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20349752/1093508

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add custom header to all responses in Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349447/add-custom-header-to-all-responses-in-web-api)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add custom HTTP Headers in Asp.Net-MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414168/how-to-add-custom-http-headers-in-asp-net-mvc)